# Generating random numbers using randn in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I am using `randn` in MATLAB to generate a set of random numbers for a given mean and standard deviation.

```
b=5000;
a=500;
y = a.*randn(100,1) + b;
sprintf('%f\n',y)
```

I expect that numbers generated would lie between 4500 to 5500. But, I see values in the range of 3000 to 6000.

Could someone explain why this happens?

Or is there any way to specify that the values should lie between mean plus/ minus 1 SD ?

Comment: Values cannot lie all between plus/minus 1SD around the mean, because the standard deviation is a measure of the average dispersion of data around the mean and you require that average to be a maximum too. The only way this would be possible is with a distribution where numbers only the take the values  *(mean-sigma)* or *(mean+sigma)*, with equal probability. `y = a.*(2*(rand(100,1)<.5)-1)+b;`

Comment: The only wat to force the values to a specific interval is to renounce the the Gaussian distribution. What distribution do you want instead? A truncated Gaussian?

Comment: @LuisMendo The mean and standard deviation is from experimental measurement. Since the data points are not available, I am trying to create the data set from the mean and standard deviation. For instance, the measurement could pertain to any physical property, like size, of a biological cell. Since most of the natural phenomena follow normal distribution I have been sampling using `randn`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the values do not lie in the interval `[4500,5500]` is that the numbers coming out of `randn()` are not confined to the interval `[-1,1]`, which is why your approach does not work as you intend, even though the general approach makes sense. The numbers coming from `randn` are drawn from the standard normal distribution, which has a standard deviation of one and a mean of zero. Theoretically, any value between `-inf` and `+inf` can come out of randn.

You could do one of the following two things, depending on what you want to do after and how that constrains your options:

**Option 1** is to generate your random numbers and divide by the maximum absolute value before you do anything else, i.e.:

```
z = randn(100,1);
z = z / max(abs(z));
y = 5000 + 500*z;
```

this will make sure that `z` does not contain any values smaller than -1 or larger than +1 (note that it does guarantee that at least one of these (-1 or +1) will be present in the array `z`). You can then use your values of `b` and `a` to translate the values to random numbers in the interval of your choice.

**Edit:** note (as pointed out in the comments on this answer) that while the above option will give you random values in the interval of your choice, it will also alter the distribution and standard deviation associated with these values. If it is important for you that the values follow a normal distribution, do not use this option.

**Option 2** is to use `rand()`, which always returns numbers from the interval `[0,1]`. Note that these come from a uniform distribution, not a normal distribution. You can then first translate these values to the interval `[-1,1]`:

```
z = rand(100,1);
z = 2*z - 1;      % Translates the interval from [0,1] to [-1,1]
```

and then generate your numbers as before; `y = 5000 + 500*z;`.

Comment: I really do not recommend the first option as it makes the distribution random. If OP really wants a limited normal distribution I would recommend the truncated normal distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Comment: Truncation will alter the standard deviation of the distribution. The question is poorly stated: is the requested std to be computed before or after truncation?

Comment: You are both correct; I will edit my answer to recommend against using the first option. It's a shame MatLab doesn't have a truncated normal distribution built in; there is a file on mathworks file exchange, but looking at the comments, it should probably not be used either.

Comment: @FlorisSA The mean and standard deviation is from experimental measurement. Since the data points are not available, I am trying to create the data set from the mean and standard deviation. For instance, the measurement could pertain to any physical property, like size, of a biological cell. Since most of the natural phenomena follow normal distribution I have been sampling using `randn`. Given this, is it appropriate to use truncated normal distribution?

Comment: Looking at your original post and your comment, I would guess the truncated normal distribution is the most appropriate, but that will still leave you with the issue of how to actually implement that in MatLab. Either way, you should probably first get clear for yourself 1) what the (desired) standard deviation is and 2) what the maximum allowed deviation from the mean is. As Brice and Ander have correctly pointed out, these values can not be the same.

Answer (score 0):

*Or is there any way to specify that the values should lie between mean plus/ minus 1 SD ?*

**No**, [by definition.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

If yo are using the **normal distribution** (`randn`) then you can not really limit your numbers to be in a range, as in the normal distribution only infinity and minus infinity have zero probability, the rest, while having a minuscule probability, can happen.

Alternatively, you can use a different distribution, such as uniform (`rand`) to constrain the randomness to a gap.

Comment: That is the case if the implied end of the question is "...and still keep a normal distribution".